# which features fundamental frequency is correlated?

Tags: python, feature-extraction, fundamental-frequency

I'm unable to compute $f_0$ (fundamental frequency) in `librosa` feature extraction. By ready much in [github issues](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/527) check the second comment. I see that $f_0$ is correlated with some other features (`like zero_crosssing`) easy to extract from `librosa`.

What are these features except for that one I give? Is this correlation super high so that they can replace $f_0$?

[data sample](https://tspace.library.utoronto.ca/bitstream/1807/24501/5/OAF_witch_happy.wav)

[site for data](https://tspace.library.utoronto.ca/handle/1807/24501)

Comment: I mean fundamental frequency, I edited the post.

Comment: updated again the post.

Comment: so, are you specifically interested in a YIN-based fundamental frequency estimate, or is the question more generally, "what features correlate well with fundamental frequency"? In either case, are we looking at a specific kind of signal (speech, instrumental music, birdsong, cars...)?

Comment: This is generally question, I'm using speech emotion data(.wav audio file with one expression).

Comment: Interesting! You might want to add a link to an example in your question :)

Comment: :) thanks, link of what exactly.

Comment: Like, upload one of your .wav files somewhere and link to that!

Comment: Ok I added it...

Comment: That's a rather long phrase with multiple words, so you've got a lot of time periods with different fundamental frequencies in each of your recordings. What's the plan with respect to that? Condense it to one "average" voiced fundamental frequency, or go for a fundamental frequencies over time feature vector?

Comment: These two option are new for me. After feature extraction, I'll apply machine learning model, so I think ` fundamental frequencies over time feature vector` is better, isn't it?
Is averaging output one vector only for a signal? may be I can test both fro comparison.

Comment: For others features I used `mean()` on them. [code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/N75KgRQXBm/) What I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer as [responded](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/527#issuecomment-554793026) here in github.